# get input filed values based on select box option from databse php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having a form.It has got select box.
Based on the value selected from the select option i want to populate the rest textfields of the form.

Below is the form :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#test').change(function(){
var val=document.getElementsById('test').value;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
        url: "get_user.php",
        data: {id:val},
        success:function()
        {


        }
            })

})
</script>


<select name="test" id="test" >
<option value="user1">user1</option>
<option value="user2">user2</option>
<option value="user3">user3</option>
<option value="user4">user4</option>
<option value="user5">user5</option>
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="Address"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Contact"/>
```

If select "user1" ,than it should call the ajax and the get the value from database for "user1" and then show the value in the text fields.

Comment: and the question is ...

Comment: i actually dont know oe to implement this functionality..

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Do you also want us to write the `get_user.php` code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Address" id="address"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Contact" id="contact"/>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#test').change(function(){
    var val=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
            url: "get_user.php",
            data: {id:val},
            success:function(data)
            {
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            $("#address").val(result.address);
            $("#name").val(result.name);
           $("#contact").val(result.contact);     
            }
         })

    </script>
```

---

PHP:

```
    //fetch data accorind to id
    $array= array();
    $array["name"] ="name";// user name
    $array["contact"] ="contact";// user contact
    $array["address"] ="address";// user address
    echo json_ecode($array);
```

Comment: @rinkusimlai Friend we can not give you all the code and we can't teach you every ting. Here you need to put `id`(address,contact,etc) to `input` elements and you need to replace the php  `array` value from database selected row value.

Comment: @ Anand Singh.....your code wont work unless changed to...var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            $("#address").val(result.address);
            $("#name").val(result .name);
           $("#contact").val(result .contact);

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#test').change(function(){
    var val=document.getElementsById('test').value;;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
            url: "get_user.php",
            data: {id:val},
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data)
            {
                 $("#add").val(data[0]);
                 $("#name").val(data[1]);
                 $("#cnt").val(data[2]);
            }
    })
})
</script>


<select name="test" id="test" >
<option value="user1">user1</option>
<option value="user2">user2</option>
<option value="user3">user3</option>
<option value="user4">user4</option>
<option value="user5">user5</option>
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="Address" id="add"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Contact" id="cnt"/>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Or you can make html in php file and then send whole html as response and in script you can bind whole html in one div or in any tag...

Comment: Show me your `get_user.php` file.

Comment: <?php

$id=$_GET['id'];

$sql="SELECT `name`,`address`,`contact` from `tbl_users` where id=$id";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$data=mysql_fetch_row($res);
?>

Comment: change your php file with this code `<?php $id=$_POST['id']; $sql="SELECT name,address,contact from tbl_users where id=$id"; $res=mysql_query($sql); $data=mysql_fetch_row($res); echo json_encode($data); ?>`

Comment: Heay rinku,If you got solution so please accept my answer so anybody can use this.

Comment: The following line of code will make your code work...var result = $.parseJSON(data); $("#address").val(result.address); $("#name").val(result .name); $("#contact").val(result .contact);